# Differences between C++ string == and compare()?

Tags: c++, string

I just read some recommendations on using

```
std::string s = get_string();
std::string t = another_string();

if( !s.compare(t) ) 
{
```

instead of

```
if( s == t )
{
```

I'm almost always using the last one because I'm used to it and it feels natural, more readable. I didn't even know that there was a separate comparison function.
To be more precise, I thought == would call compare().

**What are the differences? In which contexts should one way be favored to the other?**

I'm considering only the cases where I need to know if a string is the same value as another string.

Comment: The first one will return true where the latter one returns false, and vice versa.

Comment: The first one is barely readable while the latter is easily read and understood.

Comment: I use "compare" functions like this: `if(x.compare(y) == 0)` <- equals sign, it's equal. IMO using `!` only serves to make code unreadable.

Comment: It should be noted that == isn't going to work for you in every case.  string overloads the operator to perform a compare, so == is the same as calling a compare.  Alternatively, if you try this on objects that don't overload the == operator, you will be comparing their address in memory, and not their internal components.

Calling compare is more "safe."  In the case of using std::string, you are fine though.

Comment: One difference: `compare` return `-1` if `s` is lower than `t` and `+1` if `s` is greater than `t` while `==` return `true/false`. Nonzero integers are `true` and `0` is `false`.

Comment: The second one is better compressible by a compression algorithm as program could have more == around.

Answer (score 573, accepted):

This is what the standard has to say about `operator==`

> **21.4.8.2 operator==**
>
> ```
> template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
> bool operator==(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
>                 const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: lhs.compare(rhs) == 0.

Seems like there isn't much of a difference!

Comment: Note to readers: Please read [Frédéric Hamidi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158971/10270487) for details on the matter because there are relevant differences. Although I'm glad Bo Persson shows that the two tests will definitely return the same value.
`!s.compare(t)` and `s == t` will return the same value, but the compare function provides more information than `s == t`, and `s == t` is more readable when you don't care _how_ the strings differ but only _if_ they differ.

Answer (score 196):

[std::string::compare()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) returns an `int`:

- equal to zero if `s` and `t` are equal,
- less than zero if `s` is less than `t`,
- greater than zero if `s` is greater than `t`.

If you want your first code snippet to be equivalent to the second one, it should actually read:

```
if (!s.compare(t)) {
    // 's' and 't' are equal.
}
```

The equality operator only tests for equality (hence its name) and returns a `bool`.

To elaborate on the use cases, `compare()` can be useful if you're interested in how the two strings relate to one another (less or greater) when they happen to be different. PlasmaHH rightfully mentions trees, and it could also be, say, a string insertion algorithm that aims to keep the container sorted, a dichotomic search algorithm for the aforementioned container, and so on.

**EDIT:** As Steve Jessop points out in the comments, `compare()` is most useful for quick sort and binary search algorithms. Natural sorts and dichotomic searches can be implemented with only [std::less](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/less/).

Comment: note that this behaviour is often useful when dealing with trees or tree-like creatures.

Comment: Indeed it is, I was only pointing out the differences between the method and the equality operator :)

Comment: "In which contexts should one way be favored to the other?" just makes me think the OP can't think of possible use-cases for compare().

Comment: "if you're interested in how the two strings relate to one another" -- although idiomatic C++ for this is to use a strict weak order (like `std::less`, which is also a total order in this case) rather than a three-way comparator. `compare()` is for operations modeled on `std::qsort` and `std::bsearch`, as opposed to those modeled on `std:sort` and `std::lower_bound`.

Answer (score 59):

Internally, `string::operator==()` is using `string::compare()`. Please refer to: [CPlusPlus - `string::operator==()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/)

I wrote a small application to compare the performance, and apparently if you compile and run your code on debug environment the `string::compare()` is slightly faster than `string::operator==()`. However if you compile and run your code in Release environment, both are pretty much the same.

FYI, I ran 1,000,000 iteration in order to come up with such conclusion.

In order to prove why in debug environment the string::compare is faster, I went to the assembly and here is the code:

**DEBUG BUILD**

*string::operator==()*

```
        if (str1 == str2)
00D42A34  lea         eax,[str2]  
00D42A37  push        eax  
00D42A38  lea         ecx,[str1]  
00D42A3B  push        ecx  
00D42A3C  call        std::operator==<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (0D23EECh)  
00D42A41  add         esp,8  
00D42A44  movzx       edx,al  
00D42A47  test        edx,edx  
00D42A49  je          Algorithm::PerformanceTest::stringComparison_usingEqualOperator1+0C4h (0D42A54h)
```

*string::compare()*

```
            if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)
00D424D4  lea         eax,[str2]  
00D424D7  push        eax  
00D424D8  lea         ecx,[str1]  
00D424DB  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::compare (0D23582h)  
00D424E0  test        eax,eax  
00D424E2  jne         Algorithm::PerformanceTest::stringComparison_usingCompare1+0BDh (0D424EDh)
```

You can see that in string::operator==(), it has to perform extra operations (add esp, 8 and movzx edx,al)

**RELEASE BUILD**

*string::operator==()*

```
        if (str1 == str2)
008533F0  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-14h],10h  
008533F4  lea         eax,[str2]  
008533F7  push        dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
008533FA  cmovae      eax,dword ptr [str2]  
008533FE  push        eax  
008533FF  push        dword ptr [ebp-30h]  
00853402  push        ecx  
00853403  lea         ecx,[str1]  
00853406  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::compare (0853B80h)
```

*string::compare()*

```
            if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)
    00853830  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-14h],10h  
    00853834  lea         eax,[str2]  
    00853837  push        dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
    0085383A  cmovae      eax,dword ptr [str2]  
    0085383E  push        eax  
    0085383F  push        dword ptr [ebp-30h]  
    00853842  push        ecx  
00853843  lea         ecx,[str1]  
00853846  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::compare (0853B80h)
```

Both assembly code are very similar as the compiler perform optimization.

Finally, in my opinion, the performance gain is negligible, hence I would really leave it to the developer to decide on which one is the preferred one as both achieve the same outcome (especially when it is release build).

Comment: 'very similar'... I see no difference, do you?

Comment: me neither... they are the same thing. there's no difference

Comment: @xtofl from Tony's example the generated codes are identical in the release build, they're different in the debug builds.

Answer (score 32):

`compare` has overloads for comparing substrings. If you're comparing whole strings you should just use `==` operator (and whether it calls `compare` or not is pretty much irrelevant).

Answer (score 8):

`compare()` is equivalent to strcmp(). `==` is simple equality checking. `compare()` therefore returns an `int`, `==` is a boolean.

Answer (score 7):

`compare()` will return `false` (well, `0`) if the strings are equal.

So don't take exchanging one for the other lightly.

Use whichever makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that is not covered here is that it depends if we compare string to c string, c string to string or string to string.

A major difference is that for comparing two strings size equality is checked before doing the compare and that makes the == operator faster than a compare.

here is the compare as i see it on g++ Debian 7

```
// operator ==
  /**
   *  @brief  Test equivalence of two strings.
   *  @param __lhs  First string.
   *  @param __rhs  Second string.
   *  @return  True if @a __lhs.compare(@a __rhs) == 0.  False otherwise.
   */
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    inline bool
    operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
           const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __rhs)
    { return __lhs.compare(__rhs) == 0; }

  template<typename _CharT>
    inline
    typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_char<_CharT>::__value, bool>::__type
    operator==(const basic_string<_CharT>& __lhs,
           const basic_string<_CharT>& __rhs)
    { return (__lhs.size() == __rhs.size()
          && !std::char_traits<_CharT>::compare(__lhs.data(), __rhs.data(),
                            __lhs.size())); }

  /**
   *  @brief  Test equivalence of C string and string.
   *  @param __lhs  C string.
   *  @param __rhs  String.
   *  @return  True if @a __rhs.compare(@a __lhs) == 0.  False otherwise.
   */
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    inline bool
    operator==(const _CharT* __lhs,
           const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __rhs)
    { return __rhs.compare(__lhs) == 0; }

  /**
   *  @brief  Test equivalence of string and C string.
   *  @param __lhs  String.
   *  @param __rhs  C string.
   *  @return  True if @a __lhs.compare(@a __rhs) == 0.  False otherwise.
   */
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    inline bool
    operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
           const _CharT* __rhs)
    { return __lhs.compare(__rhs) == 0; }
```

Comment: code is formatted and shown formatted in the editor. Display got it wrong. open basic_string.h and look for operator== on your OS. The code is not mine is standard, the fact that the size check is what is missing in this thread. I also see that lots of people agree with incorrect information which defies the utility of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check string equality, use the == operator. Determining whether two strings are equal is simpler than finding an ordering (which is what compare() gives,) so it *might* be better performance-wise in your case to use the equality operator.

Longer answer: The API provides a method to check for string equality and a method to check string ordering. You want string equality, so use the equality operator (so that your expectations and those of the library implementors align.) If performance is important then you might like to test both methods and find the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose consider two string s and t.
Give them some values.
When you compare them using **(s==t)** it returns a boolean value(true or false , 1 or 0).
But when you compare using **s.compare(t)** ,the expression returns a value
(i)    **0** - if s and t are equal
(ii)  **<0** - either if the value of the first unmatched character in s is less than that of t or the length of s is less than that of t.
(iii) **>0** - either if the value of the first unmatched character in t is less than that of s or the length of t is less than that of s.