# C++ How string::compare work

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["compare" definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)
>   [Differences between C++ string == and compare()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare)

As the pages said "compare" simply compares two strings and returns an integer 0,1,-1
but in my test cases (when a=100 and b=1) it returns 2 also.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a,b,ans;
    //for(;;)
    {cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<a.compare(b)<<"\n\n";}
    return 0;
}
```

Also I am not able to understand how the function is comparing two strings (is it only number of digits)
for test cases like a=10^n b=1 it returns n.

Comment: I think it's implementation dependent. The only contract should be that it returns either a negative, positive or zero number.

Comment: Neither of those pages say `string.compare` returns -1, 0, or 1. They say it returns <0, 0, or >0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between C++ string == and compare()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to speak for "the pages". You can probably find a Youtube video that will make *any* claim about anything, so that's not a good basis to go on.

Instead, let's turn to the language standard. It says, in `[string::compare]`:

> `basic_string::compare`: `int compare(const basic_string& str) const noexcept;`
>
> *Effects:* [...] compares the two strings by calling `traits::compare(data(), str.data(), rlen)`.
>
> *Returns:* The nonzero result if the result of the comparison is nonzero. [...]

(There's an additional rule about first comparing the string lengths, which I'm omitting here.)

So then, `traits::compare` is what we need. The traits need to satisfy the "Character trait requirements", which say:

> yields: `0` if for each `i` in `[0,n)`, `X::eq(p[i],q[i])` is true; else, a negative value if, for some `j` in `[0,n)`, `X::lt(p[j],q[j])` is true and for each `i` in `[0,j)`
> `X::eq(p[i],q[i])` is true; else a positive value.

In other words, `string::compare` returns *a negative value*, zero, or *a positive value* respectively to represent lexicographic less-than, equal or greater-than. No actual result *values* are prescribed, only their sign.

A [decent web reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) should get this right, though, so you if you know how to find a good source of information, you don't always have to dig through the standard yourself.