# Error using a string in a conditional expression

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I'm very new to programming and c++

Here is a picture of the issue I am having:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQgQ7.jpg
[image: Error Message]
Earlier (not in picture), I wrote " string criteria; "  and then prompted the user to input either "gas" or "total". 
I have googled the problem and have been unable to find what is causing this error. Could someone please explain to me what is causing it and how I might fix it?

Comment: Please copy/paste the relevant piece of code and the error(s) as text into your question (by [edit]ing it).

Comment: No need for an image (at all) with a short section of code when you could have made a minimal testcase that's about that length.

Comment: where is the declaration of 'criteria'?

Comment: Well I copied the code, and then someone edited it and removed it all, so we're back to the original image. Your if (criteria.compare("gas") == 0 ) works, but I don't understand what the "0" means and why the first line of code didn't work. From looking at related questions, many others simply use the == operator and it works for them.

Comment: the 0 means that they are equals. you can see an example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: if it helped you I'll appreciate if you can mark this question as solved.

Comment: What is the type of `criteria`?

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you cant compare string that way. You compare thier address instead of thier values. Try to Google 'string compare c++'

The default behavior of the == operator is to compare two objects addresses (if they are exactly the same one). if you have 2 instance, one store at 0xff0 and the other at 0xfff - the compression is if (0xff0 == 0xfff) and of course that the answer is false.
compare used to compare their values - in this case - if the content of the string ("gas") equals to the other string content. the interesting thing is that you can override the == method to act as you want - and in string case (as shown in the related question) the == acts like compare

Comment: Why can't you compare it this way? if (myStdString == "gas") {}

Comment: It should be criteria.compare("gas") == 0

Comment: Please see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal thanks! I didn't knew it's actually the same in c++. Maybe it's because i'm using char* instead of string most of the time. I think it just a bad practice to use it that way - because it's true for string but won't work for other objects. the operation == compare pointers by default (unless you override the operator).

Comment: What are you talking about? If you don't provide an `operator==` for a user-defined type you get a compiler error. The language doesn't "compare pointers by default".

Comment: I'm talking about the concept - classes in c++ generally. You don't have to overwrite operator== for each new Class that you define. The default operator== (of object) just compare the addresses.

Comment: Nonsense, there is no _default_ `operator==` for user-defined types. Trust me, if you don't provide an `operator==` or conversion operator for a user-defined type then using `==` won't compile.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are thinking about but [here is a simple example on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Vmp5jx)

Comment: You right. guess I mixed with other programming languages. In Java for example you get the 'equals' method from object. Moreover, I just saw ideone.com for the first time so it was worth it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the class of `criteria`.

**Assume:** the class of `criteria` is `MyCriteria`.

In your class `MyCriteria`, the function `operator==(const char* pc)` is not return a proper value.

You need implement a function for the class `MyCriteria` like this:

```
bool operator==(const char* pc);
```

**PS:** I guess the function `operator==` return `void` in your class `MyCriteria`. And like this:

```
class MyCriteria
{
public:
    void operator==(const char* pc)
    {
        // code
    }
};
```

Comment: I assume that criteria is string