# Unable to successfully compare strings

Tags: c++, string, file, io, compare

The idea is to take a file and print out the amount of words in the file. Then prompt the user to enter a word, the program will then count how many times that word is iterated. However I am having trouble with being able to pick out the chosen word from the file, no matter what it still returns 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream infile;
    int i = 0;
    string word_counter;
    string file_name;
    bool opened = false;

    while (opened == false){
        cout << "Enter the name of the file to read: ";
        cin >> file_name;

        infile.open(file_name, fstream::in);
        opened = true;

        if (!infile.is_open()) {
            cout << "ERROR: CANNOT OPEN INPUT FILE" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            opened = false;
        }
    }

    while (!infile.eof()){
        infile >> word_counter;
        cout << word_counter << endl;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Read in " << i << " words\n";

    bool done = false;

    while (!done){
        string word;
        string quit;
        int x = 0;
        cout << "Enter a word to count how many times it occurs: ";
        cin >> word;

        while (!infile.eof()){
            infile << word_counter;
            if (word_counter == word){
                x++;
            }
        }

        cout << "The word \"" << word << "\" occurs " << x << " times" << endl;
        cout << "Press any key to continue, or press Q to quit: ";
        cin >> quit;

        if (quit == "q" || quit == "Q"){
            done = true;
        }
    }

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not to try using .compare() ?
some reference :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare

Comment: Why not use `strcpm(word_counter,word)` to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to rewind the file.

Add the following lines

```
infile.clear();  // Clear the EOF flag
infile.seekg(0); // rewind
```

right after

```
cin >> word;
```

Also, you are using `<<` instead of `>>` in the line

```
infile << word_counter;
```

Since you are not reading anything from the file, the enclosing `while` block stays in an infinite loop. Change that line to:

```
infile >> word_counter;
```

Comment: Ok I did that but now it just stops after prompting me to input a word, itll allow me to type but nothing happens when I hit enter.