# How does c++ compare two string using ==?

Tags: c++, string

I came across a very simple but confusing problem today.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str = "123";
    string a = "1";
    string b = "1";

    cout << ((str[0]+"") == a) << endl;
    cout << (a==str.substr(0,1)) << endl;
    cout << (a==b) << endl;

}
```

The output is:
0
1
1

Why the first compare statement is false? How does c++ compare two string when using == operator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between C++ string == and compare()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare)

Comment: What do you think is the type of str[0]?

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf I wouldn't call it a duplicate even though the titles are nearly the same. The root of the problem here is indexing a string with a character.

Answer (score 11):

`str[0]+""` is something rather odd - you take the numeric value of the first character (which is 49, assuming an ASCII encoding of the character `'1'`), and add it to a pointer to the start of an empty string. This gives you an invalid pointer, and undefined behaviour.

If you wanted to make a string out of the first character, that would be one of

```
string(1, str[0])
string(str, 0, 1)
str.substr(0, 1)
string() + str[0]
```

which would compare equal to `a`

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that when using + to combine two strings, at least one of the operands must be string type. `str[0] + "" ` violates this rule.

Answer (score 1):

They are different types,the result of the expression `str[0]+""`  is `char *` type(`""`is `char *` not `string`,for `char *` the operator `+` is not overloaded,so its behavior is undefined), but `a` is `string` type, obviously they are not equal.To see reason,you can run this code:

```
cout<<typeid(str[0]+"").name()<<endl;
cout<<typeid(a).name()<<endl;
```

Comment: I don't know which one you refer to ?

Comment: `str[0]+""`. It's `char + char const[0]`. If the arguments were in the different order, then I would understand the result of `char*`. But as it is I think the result would be `char`. I'm not sure.

Comment: It's `char*`,you can test it  using the code in my answer.