# Str.compare() or (string)A == (string)B for string comparison

Tags: c++, string, compare

I am writing a compiler that reads a file line by line, then checks the line for a command (eg. `D=AM`), splits into a substring and finds out what each command was.

Should I be using `str.compare()` or can I use an `if` statement like this below?

```
tempString = line.find("=", line.length());
if(tempString == "AM"){return 65526;}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between C++ string == and compare()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare)

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be much of a difference between the two except that using `==` will return a bool, while using `str.compare()` will return an int (specifically a 0 if true, so you would need to use it like `if(str.compare(str2) == 0)` ). You can see more about the compare function at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/ .