# c++ expected primary expression before

Tags: c++

I tried to create this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int right=0 , left=0;
    cout << "do you go left or right?" << endl;
    if (<right>) {
        <you meet a troll>
    }
    else {
        <you meet a witch>
    }
}
```

but I get many errors saying

> expected primary expression before ); before < and before 'else'.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What does this  if (<right>) <you meet a troll>
else <you meet a witch> mean?

Comment: What does being Italian have to do with making mistakes?  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I don't see what being italian has to do with anything...

Comment: i menat some mistake in the question. I would like to create an interactive fiction in which you can choose where to go, and i tried to use if else, but maybe the string is not correct

Comment: @Jacopo Altieri "I'm italian so I've probably made some mistake" -Do  you want to say that all italian are weak programmers?:)

Comment: Code demonstrates ignorance of C++ fundamentals. Can't help much other than suggest reading a book and browsing tutorial sites.

Comment: @Jacopo Altieri I advice always to go straight. In this case neither if statement will be needed.:)

Comment: Did I just meet a troll?

Comment: thank you to all, maybe I'm not ready to do this

Comment: At the moment, no. But you can be with few hour's worth of reading and experimentation. And then you'll have to do a few more hours to figure out trickier stuff. And a few more hours for another trick. And then a few more hours. And this goes on forever. Like any craft, programming is a lifetime of study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, you really need to work on some basics. There are plenty of resources out there but if you care to see your example working, the below code will do it. I think the key you're missing here is `std::cin` to get a response from the keyboard:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "do you go left or right?" << std::endl;
  std::string direction;
  std::cin >> direction;

  if(direction.compare("right") == 0)
  {
     std::cout << "you encountered a troll" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
     std::cout << "you encountered a witch" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `direction == "right"` would be clearer, especially to a beginner.

Comment: @chris I would agree with that.

Comment: @chris what's the actual difference vs std::string::compare and operator== Is there even any?

Comment: @Quest The == operator on string calls compare() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string right;
    cout << "do you go left or right?" << endl;
    cin >> right;
    if (right == "right") {
        cout << "<you meet a troll>";
    }
    else if (right == "left") {
        cout << "<you meet a witch>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? right is an int so if they answer with an right or left won't it always hit the else

Comment: @JeffS Enter `0`, it will hit the else statement. Try for yourself.

Comment: I'd still be more descriptive in the prompt then. If someone asks me if I go right or left I won't say 0, or any other number for that matter

Comment: @JeffS Edited as you want.