# can anyone help me with this c++ program there are some error

Tags: c++, ascii

i want to write a program about ascii that give you the char and ask you to to type in the decimal, which can choose only characters or all. There are so many errors and i don't know how to solve them. Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void ALL();
void character();
void ask();

int main(){
ask();
return 0;
}

void ask(){

    char type;
    char character;
    char all;
    cout<<"You can choose all or only character\ttype in(all / character)"<<endl;
    cin>>type;
    do{
if(type=='character'){
    character();
}else if(type=='all'){
    ALL();
}else{
    ask();
}
}while(1);
}

void ALL(){
int a, b;   
do{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    a=rand() %255 + 1;
    b=a;
    cout<<"What is the ascii code of "<<(char) a<<" ?"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    if(b==a){
        cout<<"You are RIGHT!!!"<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------\n----------------------------------"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"You are WRONG!!!"<<endl;
        cout<<"The ascii code of "<<(char) a<<" is "<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------\n----------------------------------"<<endl;
    }
}while(1);

}

void character(){
    int a, b, c;    
do{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    c = rand() % 2;
    if(c==1){
        b = rand() % 26 + 65;
    }else if(c==2){
        b = rand() % 26 + 97;
    }

    b=a;
    cout<<"What is the ascii code of "<<(char) a<<" ?"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    if(b==a){
        cout<<"You are RIGHT!!!"<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------\n----------------------------------"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"You are WRONG!!!"<<endl;
        cout<<"The ascii code of "<<(char) a<<" is "<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------\n----------------------------------"<<endl;
    }
}while(1);
```

}

Tt shows this at the bottom  [compiler]

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

24  11  C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\program\C++\ASCII_2.cpp [Warning] character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]

26  17  C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\program\C++\ASCII_2.cpp [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\program\C++\ASCII_2.cpp In function 'void ask()':

25  13  C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\program\C++\ASCII_2.cpp [Error] 'character' cannot be used as a function

Answer (score 1):

Change the `char type;` to `string type;`
..

Moreover, in the area where you are comparing `type == 'character'` , you have to change it to

```
if(type == "character")
{
  ...
}
```

similarly change the other comparisons.

OR

if you just want to use char here...

input either `c` or `a`

and change the condition to

```
if(type == 'c')
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: `std::string` doesn't have to use `compare()`, [it can use `==` as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare).