# Why to use compare() for strings?

Tags: c++, string

I was told not to compare strings like string1 < string2 because some compilers don't work properly that way. Is there any reason to use compare() over the !=, ==, <, <=, >, >= operators?

Comment: I'm certain a google search will turn up good information on how to compare strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9159670/1806780

Comment: look for string.compare (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

Comment: Clarification: Downvotes mean literally: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: @Almo under which category?

Comment: What do you mean by `string`?

Comment: Isn't the answer in the question: "some compilers don't work properly that way"?    So the reason would be "because it *does* work properly".

Comment: @ScottHunter: But the claim that "some compilers don't work properly" is, as far as I know, simply incorrect.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sure, but if OP already claims something is wrong with using < (however mistaken about just what the problem is), asking why one should not use it is a bit silly.

Comment: @ScottHunter: The OP received some poor advice and is asking for clarification. That's a good thing. The claim that "some compilers don't work properly", aside from being incorrect, is vague. Even if it were correct, it would be perfectly reasonable to ask how and whether `compare()` is better than `==` et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea that "some compilers don't work properly" is absurd.

If you're comparing C-style strings via `char*` pointers, then the `=`, `!=`, `<=`, ... operators compare the pointers, not the strings they point to. In that case, use the `strcmp()` function instead.  But since you're asking about the `compare` function, you're clearly not asking about C-style strings, but about C++-style `std::string` objects.

If you're comparing std::string objects, the equality and comparison operators will work correctly. Any runtime library bug that caused them to fail would be caught before the the implementation goes out the door.

The `compare` function provides a bit more functionality. Specifically, it lets you specify a substring of one of the strings being compared rather than the entire string.

Read the documentation (for example, [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/)) and decide whether you need that added functionality. If you don't, then the `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `<`, `>=`, `>` operators on `std::string` objects will work just fine. Their behavior is actually defined in terms of the `compare()` function.

There are also some locale-specific issues, but there's probably no need for you to be concerned about those just yet.

Comment: Will the compare function work, even if the characters are non-standard? IE Arabic,Chinese, or special characters? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Caperneoignis: It depends on what you mean by "work". It depends on how the characters are represented. The `==` et al operators are actually defined in terms of the `compare()` function, so both have the same advantages and disadvantages. Reading http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare will give you more information than I'm able to give you.

Comment: @Caperneoignis: Practically speaking, no. C++ has rather poor Unicode support, and you do need that for string comparisons. E.g. Unicode has (at least) two ways to represent "ä" and those will (incorrectly) compare unequal according to `string::compare` or `==`

Comment: @MSalters that is what I thought, but was not sure how to express my question properly. Because I have run into that issue before with non-English character sets, and had to make a comparator to look up the int representation of the wchar in order to get the results I was looking for. I was hoping c++11 had resolved those.

Comment: Is there an efficiency concern too? If comparing a lot of std::string would it be better to use the function compare?

Comment: @JulioSánchezCampoamor: Probably not. The behavior of the operators is defined in terms of the behavior of the `compare` function. That doesn't mean they're implemented by calling `compare`. And even if they are, the performance impact should be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

As a user notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare), there are 2-3 more operations if you use ==. But that's a veeeery small issue, if you can even treat it as one.

But compare() has some things that can be real issues - it returns 0 if the strings are equal, which can be very confusing, and this operator requires a bit longer code.

So, the only disadvantage is the readability, which can be such a pain, so I don't recommend using compare(), considering they share (most of) their advantages and disadvantages...