# c++ std::string '==' operator and Compare method is return Not equal value to equal string

Tags: c++, string, return, std

[image]

```
motion->bone_frames[0].name == model->bones[0].bone_name//it return 0 . it should be 1

motion->bone_frames[0].name.Compare(model->bones[0].bone_name)//it return 1 . it should be 0

wcscmp(motion->bone_frames[0].name.c_str(), model->bones[0].bone_name.c_str()) //it return 0  it should be 0 correct
```

I cant understand std::string compare functions why have different result to wcscmp.

Can i know why these results are different?
Is it cause of different is length?

Comment: It looks like some part of your code is adding *null terminators* (`'\0'`) to your `std::string` but `std::string` isn't (semantically) *null-terminated*.

Answer (score 5):

Because they are not equal. Check the size of your strings in the image that you've attached. In the first there are `'\0'` at the end of the string, that are characters as well.

Comment: that mean is compare method of the std::string is check the size? or just the reason of not equal is second string has not ended with null chracter??

Comment: Check @Bo Persson reply.

Answer (score 3):

`wcscmp` stops comparing when it hits `L'\0'`. A `std::wstring` will consider the `size()` of the strings.

The string `==` and `compare` will return "different" results as the first returns `true` and the second returns `0` for equal strings. See [Differences between C++ string == and compare()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare)

Answer (score 0):

The standard operator== returns `lhs.compare(rhs) == 0`.