# Qt String Comparison

Tags: c++, qt

Suppose I have:

```
QString x;
```

Is the following code fragment:

```
if(x.compare("abcdefg") == 0){
  doSomething();
}
else{
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

... functionally equivalent to:

```
if(x == "abcdefg"){
  doSomething();
}
else{
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

I could prove this for myself by writing a fairly trivial program and executing it, but I was surprised I couldn't find the question / answer here, so I thought I'd ask it for the sake of future me / others.

Comment: That's fine, but what has the `QVariant` got to do with anything? You're operating on a `QString` instance, the fact that you got it from `QVariant` is quite immaterial here because you obtain it the same way in both cases. It doesn't even matter that `canConvert<QString>` returns true. You'll get valid results when it returns false, too. Besides, why do you care what `compare` returns? You want to compare strings, use the `operator==`, it's what it's for.

Comment: @KubaOber you're right, I've removed the QVariant distractions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QString::compare`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#compare-1) will only return zero if the string passed to it and the string it is called on are equal.

[`Qstring::operator==`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-eq-eq) returns true if the strings are equal otherwise, false.

Since compare only returns zero when the strings are equal then

```
(qstrign_variable.compare("text") == 0) == (qstrign_variable == "text")
```

If `qstrign_variable` contains `"text"` in the above example.  If `qstrign_variable` contains something else then both cases evaluate to false.

Also note that `std::string` [has the same behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare)