# Error in calling function in if condition

Tags: c++

I have a very basic question in C++. I am calling the login() function in if condition and its giving me the error at time of compilation.

```
     #include<iostream>
     #include<iomanip>
     #include<string>
     using namespace std;

     void login(); 

     int main() {
         string login;
         int passcode;

         cout << "login ";
         cin >> login;

         cout << "passcode ";
         cin >> passcode;


         if(login == "admin" && passcode == 123) {
             login();
         }

         else {
             cout << "It's not the Correct Passcode ";
         }

         return 0;
         system("pause");
     } // main()

     void login() {
         cout << "You've successfully Logged into the Software ";
         return ;
     }
```

Comment: And the compile error is?

Comment: You have name collision: variable `login` vs function `login()`

Comment: For future, please read the compiler error carefully, I'm absolutely sure it says about your error. If you're still stuck, the error should be included in the text of your SO question

Comment: You are comparing string with `==` sign. You can use [compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) function

Comment: @kiner_shah: There's nothing wrong with using `==` in C++. This ain't Java you know ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba, Got it. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare).

Answer (score 4):

You have a name clash.

`login()` is a function name.

But `login` is also an instance of `std::string`.

Since it's possible for a class to *overload* the `()` operator, the compiler flags this as a potential ambiguity and emits an error.

(Note that an object instance masquerading as a function is called a *function object* - and are very useful beasts indeed, particularly before C++11.)