# String Comparison using == and compare()

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

```cpp
bool isPermutationUsingSorting(string s1, string s2) {
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    //cout << s1 << " " << s2 << endl;
    if(s1 == s2) return true;
    else false;
}

int main() {
    string s1 = "bangalore";
    string s2 = "hello";
    cout << isPermutationUsingSorting(s1, s2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am using `s1 == s2` then it printing some numeric value (`76` etc.) and if I use `s1.compare(s2)` then it is fine.
Please let me know what is difference in `==` and `compare()`.

Comment: Follow these Links to learn - http://www.sitesbay.com/java/java-string-compare

Comment: @jaybhut It's C++, not Java.

Comment: You should consider tagging the language to the question so people know what you're asking about.

Comment: `if(s1 == s2) return true; else false;` - did you mean `if(s1 == s2) return true; else return false;`?

Comment: @GSerg good catch! If OP did not, then it's undefined behavior and 76 is a pretty much expected gibberish value.

Comment: Provided typos are fixed, this should be a possible duplicate of [Differences between C++ string == and compare()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9158894/11683)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I got the logic..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between C++ string == and compare()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare)

Comment: Better just `return (s1 == s2);`.