# Warnings and Errors with declaration of multi-character character

Tags: c++

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFB2X.jpg)

Here's my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class Dragon
{
   public:
       char element[30];
       int energy;
};
int main()
{
   Dragon dragon;
   char name[30];
   cout<<"Enter element.\n\n";
   cin>>name;

if(name=='Hell')
{
    strcpy(dragon.element,"Hell Dragon");
    dragon.energy=15000000;
}
else if(name=='Dark')
{
    strcpy(dragon.element,"Dark Dragon");
    dragon.energy=1000000;
}
else
    cout<<"Unknown Dragon.";

cout<<"\nDragon's element = "<<dragon.element<<"\nDragon's energy level = "<<dragon.energy;

getch();

return 0;
```

}

Just tried this program on my own in C++ and have problems in fixing the following errors-

[Errors and Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHAuj.jpg)

If you do have an idea on how I can modify this, please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: well , a string should be included in double quotes, example: "Hello" , if u r using character array , use strcmp function to compare strings, and kindly consider looking up for syntax mistakes or error in google , or searchbox first .  This Link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: You can't use `==` with character arrays.  Use either `strcmp` or if you want to use `==`, use `std::string`.  Since you are using character arrays, the `==` is comparing pointers not contents.

Comment: If you are going to use `char[]` instead of `std::string`, use `cin.getline` instead of `cin >>`.  The `getline` allows you to specify the maximum number of characters to input, *so you don't overflow your character array*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cause of your issues is that `==` can't be used to compare contents of character arrays.

**Solution 1:  Use `std::string`**
The `std::string` data type is the preferred data structure in C++ for text strings.

The `std::string` has overloaded `==` for comparing strings.

The `std::string` also has a `find` method for searching for a substring.

**Solution 2:  Use `strcmp`**
The C language uses character arrays for strings.  The C language also has `str*()` functions for processing character arrays.

The C++ language uses the `str*()` functions for processing the C-Style strings (character arrays).

Use `strcmp` to compare character arrays with string literals:

```
if (strcmp(name, "Hell") == 0)
```

You may also want to use `strstr` for finding substrings or `strchr` for finding characters in a character array (C-style string).